# Getting issue with correct image when share a post from website to Google plus

Tags: php, google-plus

I am trying to share my website post into Google plus.I have used below code to achive this:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode(url());?>" class="btn btn-danger" target="_blank" title="Google +"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> share</a>
```

and as well as I used meta tags:

```
<meta itemscope itemtype="<?php echo url();?>"/>
<meta itemprop="name" content="<?=$title;?>"/>
<meta itemprop="description" content="<?=strip_tags(substr($post['post_content'],0,1000 ));?>"/>
<meta itemprop="image" content="<?php echo $imagePath;?>"/>
```

It's share correct post title and description but not sharing correct image of that post.

Can anyone help me to find out that what exactly I need to change?

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: Usually it's an issue with the image being too small or Google caching an older version of the page. We can't help without seeing the live page though.

Comment: Thank you abraham for your suggestion.
I shared 200px*200px image size picture to google plus. Have we not any option for clear Google caching an older version of the page?

Comment: Make sure you follow the size requirements on https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/article-rendering. Google+ doesn't have a way to clearing their cache, your best option is to change the URL.